# Commutative diagrams and other symbols in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Recently, I started using `emacs` and I found `org-mode`. I like its concept, but I'm having a lot of troubles for note-taking in LaTeX.

For instance, when I try to put the symbol `$\varinjlim$` it simply doesn't show anything, even if I try to include the package using `#+LATEX_HEADER`.

Another problem is that I don't have any idea about how I can use a commutative diagrams package (like the package `diagrams`) in `org-mode`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

Inline LaTeX will not, by default, be displayed in org-mode. You can however preview LaTeX symbols if you are using XEmacs by running the command M^x org-preview-latex-fragment.  by default this is bound to C^c C^x C^l.  You will need to be in a buffer that is related to an actual file.  Emacs uses LaTeX to generate images for each inline symbol and then inserts the images as an overlay.

You can read more about this here:
http://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html#Previewing-LaTeX-fragments

Comment: Note this solution works also with GNU Emacs.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. But when I say that it doesn't show anything, is when I compile, not when I try to preview in emacs.